# Does $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\big(f(x)\big)^{1/4}<\infty$ imply that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)x^{1+\delta}<\infty$ for some $\delta>0$?

Tags: integration

If $f$ is strictly positive function with $\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \big(f(x)\big)^{1/4}<\infty$ does it then follow that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)x^{1+\delta}<\infty$ for some $\delta>0$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} 1_{ [n,n+\frac{1}{n^2}]}(x)$$
then, since $f(x)=f(x)^{1/4}$
we have $$\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)^{1/4}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
but 
$$\int_{\mathbb R} xf(x)dx\sim \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{n}=\infty$$

Maybe it works with stronger assumptions.

Comment: thanks, I think taking $g(x)=f(x)+e^{-x^2}$ works